# How do I sort a table according to another table column?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables Forum and Interest. 
Forum Table includes Forum Title and Category. 
Interest Table includes Username, Category and Interest. Interest is either 1 or 0. 
How do I display a table with all Forum details sorted according to Interest for a specific user?

An Example of Result wanted with Interest column

```
| Forum Title | Category  | Interest| 
| ----------- | --------- | ------- |
| Forum1      | Category2 | 1       |
| Forum1      | Category3 | 1       |
| Forum2      | Category5 | 1       |
| Forum1      | Category1 | 0       |
| Forum2      | Category4 | 0       |
```

Comment: please provide a details on what u have tried so far to resolve the issue

Comment: Please add the definition of forum and intrest table

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `join`

```
select Forum_Title, Category,Interest
from Forum f join Interest i on f.Category=i.Category
where username='Your specific User'
order by interest desc
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you don't have to explicitly select the interest to do this:

```
select f.Forum_Title, f.Category
from Forum f
where f.username = ?
order by (select i.interest from interest i where f.Category = i.Category) desc;
```

You can add a second key if you want each group ordered alphabetically.

More important than showing an alternative method for looking up the interest is the `?`.  Presumably, you are doing this from some application.  The value for the user should be passed in as a parameter rather than as an explicit value.

Further, you should have a table of `users` and then use `user_id` for the foreign key relationships in all the other tables.